# U.S. Health Insurance for road warriors

Tags: usa, health, insurance

I've begun to travel around the U.S. as an independent contractor.  Conventional HMO and PPO medical insurance plans and policies for individuals (such as those available through healthcare.gov) all appear to be designed around limited geographical areas.

What are good options for finding medical insurance that I can use anywhere in the country?

Answer (score 4):

I have used Aetna PPO California and BlueCross BlueShield PPO Massachusetts through my employers: they both cover all US states equally (I tried it myself by receiving medical coverage in other states). Coverage is much more limited if outside the US.

Answer (score 2):

[This website](https://www.cignaglobal.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA2ITuBRDkARIsAMK9Q7OIRyeQGicxAtPPj004eBBB6vDcaHMLxTB27XFcRofIIrI38gCE4ToaAtPiEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) (no affiliation) offers health insurance for all of the USA. When searching around for quotes, most websites redirect to that page.

Comment: Nice: that purports to offer *global* coverage!

Comment: I do not believe that policy will cover US residents for healthcare in the US. Note that on the policy page, all plans exclude the US https://www.cignaglobal.com/international-medical-insurance